# how to get complete parent node name and child node name in jstree while selecting the child node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am getting the child tree id:

[image]

But when I am selecting all child node then I am getting parent node id.

[image]

I want to get its complete hierarchy of parent node names.

for example :-

```
node 1 >node 1 child node 1 

node 1 >node 1 child node 2
```

Here is my all code

```
<div id="demo1" class="demo">
  <ul>
    <li id="phtml_1">
      <a href="#">node 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="phtml_3">
          <a href="#"> node 1 Child node 1</a>
        </li>
        <li id="phtml_2" >
          <a href="#">node 1 Child node 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="phtml_4">
      <a href="#">Root node 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script type="text/javascript" class="source">
    $(function () {
      $("#demo1").jstree({ 
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "checkbox", "sort", "ui" ]
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
<h4 id="menu" name="menu">
  click menu
</h4>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#menu").click(function() {
    var ids = $('#demo1 li.jstree-checked').filter(function() { 
      return $(this).parents('li.jstree-checked').length == 0; 
    }).map(function() { 
      return this.id;
    }).get();

    alert(ids);

  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://johntang.github.io/JsTree/_lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://johntang.github.io/JsTree/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
```

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_path` method for that as below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/8rqa3enf/).

```
var glue = ' > ', // if you want a specific string separator, otherwise use false
    showIds = true; // if false names will be shown

$('#tree').jstree().get_path(data.node, glue, showIds )
```